# Knockout.js rows won't validate in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'am using MVC, C#, Razor, and Knockout.js

**Models > SKUPrice.cs**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "SRP")]
public Decimal SRP { get; set; }
```

**Controllers > SKUPriceController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Create(int id = 1)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<SKUPrice> skuprices)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        foreach (SKUPrice skuprice in skuprices) 
        {
            db.SKUPrices.AddObject(skuprice);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
return View();
```

**Views > SKUPrice > Create.cshtml**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].SRP)
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SRP must be a number."
                    data-val-required="The SRP field is required." name="[0].SRP" type="number" value="0" step="0.25">
                <span class="help-block"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="[0].SRP"
                    data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" onclick="" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addPrice">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: SKUPrice">
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SRP must be a number."
                data-val-required="The SRP field is required." type="number" value="0" step="0.01" data-bind="attr: { name: '[' + ($index() + 1) + '].SRP'}">
            <span class="help-block"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"
                data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': '[' + ($index() + 1) + '].SRP'}"></span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
        <i class="fa fa-close" data-bind="click: $parent.removePrice" style="cursor: pointer; color: Red;"></i>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

**Scripts > main.js**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.SKUPrice = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addPrice = function () {
        self.SKUPrice.push({ count: "" });
    };

    self.removePrice = function () {
        self.SKUPrice.remove(this);
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

When I enter a non-number in first row and click save it validated, but when I add a second row and enter a non-number value it doesn't validate other rows except for the first row. What is the problem with this?

Seems like the **data-val** in `<input type="text" data-val="true" />` is not working?

Comment: Can we see more of rour main.js? Somewhere you presumably have some code that applies the validation plugin - I think that's key - I will sketch up an answer below to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is when you add a new item to the `SKUPrice` array, Knockout pushes a new `<td>` into your DOM, but this new DOM element has not had the MVC unobstrusive validation applied to it. I am not expert with MVC, but you could try adding this line to `addPrice`:

```
self.addPrice = function () {
    self.SKUPrice.push({ count: "" });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#yourFormSelector')
};
```

where of course `#yourFormSelector` is a jQuery selector to get to your `<form>` element, which I can't see in your HTML.

As an aside, I spotted that you have no `<tr>` inside your `<tbody>` - is that deliberate? This might be more normal:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: SKUPrice">
    <tr>
        <td>
            inputs...
        </td>
        <td>
            close link...
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I found an error in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in code lines of `$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {` with this error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**. Why did that error occurred?

Comment: I think you prob should to open a new Question to discuss that, rather than doing it here. Also, it is OK to accept your own answer, and indeed it is helpful to do so: it will tell people the question has been answered, which is useful for other people thinking of answering it or looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Answered it without using the `JQuery.unobtrusive.validation.js` of MVC and used just a simple query for validation.

```
$("input[name*=SRP]").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        err++;
        $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']").html("The field SRP is required.");
    } else if(isNaN($(this).val())) {
        err++;
        $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']").html("The field SRP must be a number.");
    } else {
        $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']").html("");
    }
});
```